# Regarding SWT Table, Has any one worked on Table SWT

Tags: swt

How does SWT Table store the Table Items internally,Does it use an Array, or Array List  or a Linked List..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table stores all its TableItems in Arrays as TableItem[] items.

Is there any reason you are looking into implementation details ?

Comment: There is a method setHashLookUp(boolean value) on TableViewer,Can any one tell me the purpose of having it...

Answer (score 0):

According [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_package=org.eclipse.swt&as_lang=&as_filename=&as_class=Table&as_function=&as_license=&as_case=) in most implementations as arrays. (`Table` is implemented for each platform.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several class instance need to create to fill value in Table in SWT:

1) **public class IDEditor extends ViewPart** : First create view Part in Eclipse plugin
    now add TableViewer in ViewPart

```
TableViewer tv = new TableViewer(composite);
// Set the content and label providers
tv.setContentProvider(new IDContentProvider());
tv.setLabelProvider(new IDLabelProvider());
tv.setSorter(new IDViewerSorter());

// Set up the table
Table table = tv.getTable();
  table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    // Add the first name column
    TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    tc.setText("ID Name");
```

2) **IDContentProvider class:**
      public class IDContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider{

```
  }
```

3) **IDLabelProvider class:**
   public class IDLabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider{

}

4) **IDViewerSorter class:**
   public class IDViewerSorter extends ViewerSorter{

}